# CKEditor and line height

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm creating a desktop to mobile website converter and having a line height problem.

I have 2 images demonstrating this:

Desktop (Correct):

[image]

Mobile (Line problems)
[image]

The CSS:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1.428571429 !important;
```

Previously I tried CKEditor with div block mode instead of paragraphs to help spacing and now went back to the default mode.

The mobile website converter works by scaling the page element by element by resizing properties like font size, width and height.

Problem: 
CKEditor places the font size on a span tag inside the paragraph. The default font size for the body is 13px. The paragraph has 13px font size but I would need it set to the maximum the user specified but the default needs to stay at 13px.

So if the user created a paragraph at 6px, the paragraph tag needs to be also the same font size for the line height to work.

It works on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/1o7w8emx/
But not on http://zen8.prosoftwareuk.co.uk/p/1848/home

Mobile converter text box code:

```
var t = $('<div id="textbox">').html( text );
var width_float = 960 / 320; // 960px Example Page Width To Mobile 320px
var mobile_limit_font = 3;

t.find('*').each(function(ti,tv){
    var c = parseInt( $(tv).css('font-size') ) / width_float;
    c = Math.floor( c );
    c = ( c < mobile_limit_font ? mobile_limit_font : c );

    $(tv).css({
      'font-size': c + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Added examples at JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/1o7w8emx/ and at http://zen8.prosoftwareuk.co.uk/p/1848/home

Comment: On the second example you have a `<p>` element with `<span>` inside. The `p` element has font-size of 13px, while the `span` is 6px. The line-height of 1.4 is related to the 13px instead of the 6px. If you change the `span` elements to `div` or `p` it will fix your problem. Another option is to change the `span`'s display from inline to inline-block (or block).